# Intel 82845G Video Crash workaround

Tags: x11, window-manager, awesome, intel

I have the Intel 82845G video card and trying to get X11 working with it. It routinely crashes with artifacts. I know the existing history with this driver and X11 and I am about to buy a replacement video card but decided I will check here first to see if anyone has had any success with it.

I tried it with Linux Mint XFCE, and Crunchbang openbox. I made sure the BIOS onboard video memory is at max, and different options in `xorg.conf` like disabling DRI.

Eventually I want to use [awesome wm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awesome_%28window_manager%29). Will changing the wm have any effect on video crashing, or is this solely a problem between Intel's driver and X11 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by setting the framebuffer option for the 82845G card to false, disabling Xinerama and running on 1024x768. When I go up to 1024 vertical resolution like on 1280x1024, the video crashes with artifacts frequently, and Xinerama would freeze the system. I only encountered one freeze with artifacts on 1024x768, and that was coming out of standby power mode. If it becomes an issue, I will install another nvidia card as the 8400GS I have works well.

I have two openbox sessions running on two displays and it suits my needs, browser on the left, development on the right. I was worried as I usually have firebug running on my right display, but I'm implementing guard with livereload which should keep the need for full screen firebug minimal. If it's an issue, I will switch to fiddler.

Comment: Framebuffer option was disabled in xorg.conf. I saw this when having x create the initial config file with # Xorg -configure . Later I may look into using specific intel drivers like i810, but the system seems stable right now so I'm sticking with it.